# List of citation locations in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I would like, at the end of a bibliography item, a list of links to the citation point in the document, perhaps with the page number (and some solution if there are two citations in the same page).
For instance in the following MWE there should be something like

> cited at 1, 3, 3^2

Is there a package doing that ?
There must be, but I do not know how to instruct the search engine to find it.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{Author2012,
    Author = {Author, A},
    Title = {Article},
    Year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}
First citation \cite{Author2012}.

\chapter{Example}
Second citation \cite{Author2012}.
Third citation \cite{Author2012}.


\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}` but it will only produce one link per page. (It is half possible to have it mention the same page multiple times [`\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{#4}`], but the links will not go to the specific citation, but just to the general page.)

Comment: @moewe Thank you for your reply. For me is nearly impossible to make it work